# How to insert STRUCT values in Google Big Query?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

We have standart analytics table in GoogleBigQuery:

We need to insert new data, with:

```
event_date,
event_timestamp,
event_name,
event_params.key.value,
event_params.value.string_value,
device.advertising_id
```

And I can't understand, how i can do it, with "event_params.key.value, event_params.value.string_value, device.advertising_id".
Can you help me make a request?

Somethink like this

```
INSERT 
INTO `table`.`analytics_183424923.events_intraday_20191120`
(
  `event_date`,
  `event_timestamp`,
  `event_name`,
  `device.advertising_id`
) 
VALUES 
(
  '20191120',
  1574212435206765,
  'custom_event',
  'deviceId'
);
```

Here our table in JSON.

```
[
  {
    "event_date": "20191120",
    "event_timestamp": "1574236440549659",
    "event_name": "SHOW_INTERSTITIAL",
    "event_params": [
      {
        "key": "has",
        "value": {
          "string_value": "0",
          "int_value": null,
          "float_value": null,
          "double_value": null
        }
      },
      {
        "key": "firebase_event_origin",
        "value": {
          "string_value": "app",
          "int_value": null,
          "float_value": null,
          "double_value": null
        }
      }
    ],
    "event_previous_timestamp": "1574236295986010",
    "event_value_in_usd": null,
    "event_bundle_sequence_id": "19",
    "event_server_timestamp_offset": "6519649",
    "user_id": null,
    "user_pseudo_id": "1d28ad03ef14b6991cbbcf5c69c5db3f",
    "user_properties": [
      {
        "key": "first_open_time",
        "value": {
          "string_value": null,
          "int_value": "1538305200000",
          "float_value": null,
          "double_value": null,
          "set_timestamp_micros": "1538302277504649"
        }
      }
    ],

    "device": {
      "category": "mobile",
      "advertising_id": "8ae303e4-b94b-4599-929c-c8ae3c418ed7",
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
INSERT 
INTO `table`.`analytics_183424923.events_intraday_20191120`
(
  `event_date`,
  `event_timestamp`,
  `event_name`,
  `device`
) 
VALUES 
(
  '20191120',
  1574212435206765,
  'custom_event',
  struct<category string, advertising_id string>('mobile', 'deviceId')
);
```

A simpler form would work in your case, but sometimes your have to specify the full field list of a struct as above.

Simpler one:

```
...
VALUES 
(
  '20191120',
  1574212435206765,
  'custom_event',
  ('mobile', 'deviceId')
);
```